# How to pass a function arguments to ggplot2 correctly with some direct column names inputs and one column name taken from a list in a loop?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wrote this code to create one or multiple `ggplot`s:

```
#list of columns names in my dataframe:
metals_to_analys <- c("51 V ug/g","52 Cr ug/g","75 As ug/g","27 Al ug/g","55 Mn ug/g","60 Ni ug/g","63 Cu ug/g","66 Zn ug/g","95 Mo ug/g","111 Cd ug/g","88 Sr ug/g","47 Ti ug/g")

#general dynamic list to design the function:
design <- list(
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=treatment), na.rm=TRUE),
  geom_jitter(aes(shape=season), na.rm=TRUE),
  stat_n_text(size=3),
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(control="palegreen4",`external control`="palegreen3",`capture: external control`="palegreen",pollution="tomato3")),
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"), legend.position = "bottom"),
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", label = "p.format", size = 5, na.rm=TRUE)
  )

#the function to create a single ggplot and pass the inputs as variables
general_plot <- function(df,x.var,y.var,fill.var){
  x.var <- enquo(x.var)
  y.var <- enquo(y.var)
  fill.var <- enquo(fill.var)
  ggplot(data=df, aes(x=!!x.var, y=!!y.var, fill=!!fill.var))
}

#the "final" function to run the plot function inside a loop of col.names:
plot_generator <- function(df,x.var,fill.var){
  for (metal in metals_to_analys){
  print(general_plot(df=df,x.var=x.var, !!sym(metal), fill.var=fill.var)+design)
  }
}
```

When I run this loop I get the desired output:

```
#my attempt to check the "general_plot" function:
for (metal in metals_to_analys){
  print(general_plot(df=subset_AC_with_breeding_col,x.var=treatment, !!sym(metal), fill.var=treatment)+design)
  }
```

but when Im trying to run the function using this line:
`plot_generator(subset_AC_with_breeding_col,treatment,treatment)`
I get an error:

```
Error in `geom_boxplot()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error:
! object 'treatment' not found
Backtrace:
  1. global plot_generator(subset_AC_with_breeding_col, treatment, treatment)
  3. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(...)
  5. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  6. ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
 13. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 14. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 15. ggplot2 (local) compute_aesthetics(..., self = self)
 16. ggplot2:::scales_add_defaults(...)
 17. base::lapply(aesthetics[new_aesthetics], eval_tidy, data = data)
 18. rlang (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
```

I've tried:

- to write it like that: `plot_generator(subset_AC_with_breeding_col,"treatment","treatment")` but I'm losing the X axis ticks and getting the axis headline "x.var", while when using the loop outside the function I'm getting the correct desired output.
- to specify the vector like this: `plot_generator(subset_AC_with_breeding_col,subset_AC_with_breeding_col$treatment,subset_AC_with_breeding_col$treatment)` but instead of the X axis title ("treatment") it writes "x.var".
- to replace the `"treatment"` inside the `geom_boxplot(aes(fill=treatment))` in the "design" list with `"x.var"`, but I believe it is not related since the list works great as it is in the loop version and also in the first "general_plot".

If u could please help me understand how to pass these inputs smoothly? I don`t see any reason why the function output should be any different than the loop output...

tnx!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. We can't run your code because `subset_AC_with_breeding_col` is not defined. Also, list all packages you are using. You are using some stat function that do not ship with `ggplot2`.

Comment: Try `print(general_plot(df=df, x.var={{x.var}}, .data[[metal]], fill.var={{fill.var}})+design)` in your `plot_generator` function

Comment: @MrFlick omg perfect! tnx!!!